# How can I do column wise counts and change value when the frequency is less than 3?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a dateframe with a lot of rows with some low frequency values.  I need to do column wise counts and then change the value for when the frequency is less than 3.

DF-Input

```
Col1     Col2     Col3       Col4
 1        apple    tomato     apple
 1        apple    potato     nan
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        grape    tomato     banana
 1        pear     tomato     banana
 1        lemon    tomato     burger
```

DF-Output

```
Col1     Col2     Col3       Col4
 1        apple    tomato     Other
 1        apple    Other      nan
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        Other    tomato     banana
 1        Other    tomato     banana
 1        Other    tomato     Other
```

Comment: I don't think Ayhan's original solution handles the NaN in the original dataframe for this question.  I suggest this isn't a dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `where` with `value_counts`:

```
df.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x).transform('count')>2), 'Other')
```

Output:

```
       Col2    Col3    Col4
Col1                       
1     apple  tomato   Other
1     apple   Other  banana
1     apple  tomato  banana
1     apple  tomato  banana
1     apple  tomato  banana
1     apple  tomato  banana
1     Other  tomato  banana
1     Other  tomato  banana
1     Other  tomato   Other
```

#### Update: To handle NaN in original dataframe:

```
d = df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x).transform('count'))
df.where(d.gt(2.0).where(d.notnull()).astype(bool), 'Other')
```

Output:

```
       Col2    Col3    Col4
Col1                       
1     apple  tomato   Other
1     apple   Other     NaN
1     apple  tomato  banana
1     apple  tomato  banana
1     apple  tomato  banana
1     apple  tomato  banana
1     Other  tomato  banana
1     Other  tomato  banana
1     Other  tomato   Other
```

Comment: Good one! I need to remember df.where :)

Comment: this isn't exactly what you need, this is everywhere where the `!= idmax()` but it should be for those less than 3...

Comment: Yes, I don't use df.mask as well enough!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are correct.  I've fixed for frequency less than 3

Comment: how do you specify specific columns?

Comment: what about the nan ?